# Can I ignore html dom elements that are inside other dom element?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a piece of javascript code that I wrote to grab the html of a certain dom element, the problem is there is another element inside that dom element and it's rendering as html.

example:

```
<p>
    test.append("<ul />");
</p>
```

Is there a way to ignore the ul inside the p without having to replace < with `&lt;` and things of that sort?

The javascript code I wrote just takes the current text in the provided dom and places code lines next to it. Such as an IDE would.

Comment: `<p>` cannot have block elements inside of it...

Comment: Your example is confusing, but if you want a copy of an element without its child elements: element.cloneNode(false)

Comment: not only that, but is that plain jQuery just inline with your html?

Comment: Your question as a whole is confusing indeed. The part "Is there a way to ignore the ul inside the p without having to replace < with &lt; and things of that sort?" implies that all you want to do is *display* the JavaScript code inside the `<p>` element, right? Or do you need help with that code doing something?

Comment: DOM elements don't "have html", but child-nodes. (HTML exists in source code, not in the DOM)

Comment: @Šime Vidas That wasn't helpful..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XHTML and HTML 5, you can use CDATA sections so that you don't have to escape critical characters:

```
<p>
<![CDATA[
    test.append("<ul />");
]]>
</p>
```

**Update**: I don't know of any method to achieve that for HTML <= 4 documents. CDATA is implicitly assumed for e.g. `<script>` content, but certainly not for `<p>`. However, why not properly escape characters (e.g. `<` -> `&lt;`) in the first place? If your content is static, your text editor might help you with that; if it is dynamic (generated by PHP or whatever), there are functions to do that for you.

Comment: +1 to that man I think that actually understood this question... laf.

Comment: You can use an explicit CDATA block like that in XHTML if and only if you serve it with a XML mime type (e.g. `application/xhtml+xml`). The same goes for HTML5. It does not work when serving your markup as `text/html` in any version of (X)HTML.

Comment: Sorry, the example was rough. This is the answer I needed. Thanks.